# RowCallback function in datatable is removing expression from anchor tag?

Tags: angularjs, datatables

I'm using AngularJs expressions here.So, when I compile `row`s using `rowCallback` function, my expression in anchor tag is removed. What is the solution of this problem?

```
rowCallback: function(row) {  
if (!row.compiled) {
  $compile(angular.element(row))($scope);
  row.compiled = true;
}  }
```

And here is the anchor tag that i'm using in defaultContent of datatable.

```
"defaultContent": "<a class='btn btn-sm btn-default'ng-href='#{{exp_url}}'>click me</a>"
```

In browser on inspect after datatable is populated above anchor tag becomes

```
<a class="btn btn-sm btn-default"ng-href="#">click me</a>
```

And it is causing problems because when I click on button nothing happens.

Solution or workaround?

Comment: I guess `exp_url` refers to a property in your `ng-repeat`? It cannot work, it just renders out `ng-href='#{{exp_url}}'`, DataTables  is **not** part of the rest of the angular scope or the `ng-repeat` child scope. Why not just render out defaultContent the "angular way" as the rest?

Comment: I'm not using ng-repeat. but data is present in $scope.data, But why it is eliminating the expression or it evaluates it, when compiled? @davidkonrad

Comment: and what do you mean by `defaultContent render` like "angular way"? Are you reffering to use `ng-repeat` and populate data  in datatable?

Comment: OK, Still, you do not have access to `$scope.data` nor the column data from `defaultContent`, it is purely static. You could use a render function and  `return '<a class="btn btn-sm btn-default" href="'+data+'"'>'` ....

Comment: Can you create a snippet and post it as answer, that would be very nice of you. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunetely I have to leave,  see https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render if you have specified `data: 'exp_url'` to the column definition you could use `render:  function(data, type, row, meta) { ...  }`

Comment: @davidkonard i posted the answer, if you think, i get your idea right then upvote it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed `davidkonrad` instructions and it really worked out. Key is to use `render function` instead of `defaultContent`.

And in your render function return the anchor tag.

```js
"render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
  return '<a  href="#/app/customer/'+ full.customer_id+'" >Download</a>'
}
```

This will work perfectly!

Don't use `ng-href attribute` because it will create another attribute with `href name`. Functionality will remain `same`. Here is the `inspect code` how it will look like:-

```
<a ng-href="#/app/customer/100" href="#/app/customer/100">Download</a>
```

This was the answer to my question.